# Good practices for creating a Web API 2 & EF based system

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

I am creating a Web API 2 application based on Entity Framework. My questions are about good practices involved in creating Web API 2 & EF based system.

Suppose that I have class `Payment` containing class `Address`.

```
public class Payment()
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public Address PaymentAddress{ get; set; }
}

public class Address ()
{
    public string StreetName{ get; set; }
    public string City{ get; set; }
}
```

Question 1:

Does my Web API should allow for changing `Address` from endpoint PUT /payments (I mean changing `Address`'s properties not the whole object) called Solution 1

Question 2:

or maybe PUT /payments should update only simple properties of `Payment` without `Address` properties? In this scenario `Address` properties could by changed by endpoint PUT /payments/{paymentId}/address (called Solution 2)?

Question 3:

Currently I have implemented Solution 1 but I have problem to set context properly for `Payment` updates with updated `Address`'s properties. I have to manually change EF State value of `Address`. If solution 2 would solve my problem?

Question 4

By default EF one-to-many relation is defined automatically like in my example. But I can use ForeignKey attribute mark column as foreign key. Why this solution is better? Does is help in anything?

```
public class Payment()
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public int AddressId{ get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public Address PaymentAddress{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You might get better responses if this was multiple questions.